# Open a new window when a particular cell of a row in a QTableView is clicked in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a table which displays some dynamic data. I need to implement a feature whereby if the user clicks a designated column of the row (note that this particular column doesn't need to display any data. It is simply needs to function as a place to receive this special user input (a click is what I have in mind)), I should be able to open a new window. Note that this new window DOES not need to edit the contents of the table at all.. In fact it will display some other contextual data which is not present in the table itself.

How do I implement this in Qt?

Answer (score 2):

Use Signals and slots. Hope this will be helpful!

```
connect(tableView,SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex &)),this,SLOT(function(const QModelIndex &)));

void function(const QModelIndex &index)
{
   int row=index.row();
   int column=index.column();
   dialog->show();
   //do the stuff 

}
```